# ExtJS GridHeaderFilters not a constructor

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs

I'm trying to add row filters in ExtJS and I'm getting this error in FireFox:

```
TypeError: Ext.ux.grid.GridFilters is not a constructor
```

I'm going off of [this](https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?41658-Grid-header-filters) model. Is there a better way to add row filters to an XMLStore?

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/238v)

```
plugins: [new Ext.ux.grid.GridHeaderFilters()],
        columns: [{
                text: 'Title',
                width: 150,
                dataIndex: 'Title',
                filter: [{xtype:"textfield"},{xtype:"textfield"}]
            }, {
                text: 'Description',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'Description',
                filter: [{xtype:"textfield"},{xtype:"textfield"}]
            }, {
                text: 'Modified',
                width: 90,
                dataIndex: 'Modified',
                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                format: 'm/d/Y'

            }],
            filter: {
                xtype: "combo",
                mode: "local",
                store: [["A","Type1"],["B","Type2"]],
                triggerAction: "all"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, that plugin was written for Ext JS 3.x (released 2009?) and your fiddle loads Ext JS 6.x. There have been significant changes between the two versions. The fiddle doesn't actually load the plugin source, so it can't be initiated.

Assuming you're using 6.x, the Ext JS examples have a good reference:
http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/examples/classic/grid/filtered-buffered-store.html